# How to set thumbnails for the list in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Below is the code for file browser.It works fine for browsing files and folders on the device. I would like to display image thumbnail next to the name of the image.How can I achieve that?If someone could help in modifying this code to add image thumbnails. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;

private String root;
private TextView myPath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
 myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
 item = new ArrayList<String>();
 path = new ArrayList<String>();
 File f = new File(dirPath);
 File[] files = f.listFiles();

 if(!dirPath.equals(root))
 {
  item.add(root);
  path.add(root);
  item.add("../");
  path.add(f.getParent()); 
 }

 for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
  File file = files[i];

  if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
   path.add(file.getPath());
      if(file.isDirectory()){
       item.add(file.getName() + "/");
      }else{
       item.add(file.getName());
      }
  } 
 }

 ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
 setListAdapter(fileList); 
}
```

//The main layout with a ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="No Data"
    />
```

Comment: what do you mean by "add image thumbnails"  ???? to where you need to add thumbnails ??

Comment: In the listview, thumbnail and then the name of the file

Comment: you want to set same image for all list items or different images  ?

Comment: image for all the list items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

1. Create layout for single listview row as follows,

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="180dp"
       android:layout_height="180dp"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout >
   ```
2. Put the required icon within drawable folder and Define class for extended from BaseAdapter

   ```
   public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<MyModel> data;

   public AllListAdapter(Context con, ArrayList<String> dt) {
    this.context = con;
    this.data = dt;
   }


    // other overriden methods


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;

    TextView name;
    ImageView image;


   if (row == null) 
   {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_single_list_row, null);

       name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);
       image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
   } 
   else 
   {
       name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);
       image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
   }

   name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
   image.setBackgroundDrawable(this.context.getResources().getDrawable(<your icon>))

   return row;
    }  
    }
   ```
3. Set data to the list

   ```
       ListAdapter allListadapter = new ListAdapter(this,item);
       your_list.setAdapter(allListadapter);
   ```